# Got error : "443 no HTTPS proxy: resolving host login.docker.com: lookup login.docker.com: no such host" while login to Docker desktop app

Tags: docker, macos, docker-app

I can log in to https://hub.docker.com/ , however not in desktop app [error message appearing in Docker app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4IYG.png)

Error:
Post "https://login.docker.com/oauth/token": dialing login.docker.com:443 no HTTPS proxy: resolving host login.docker.com: lookup login.docker.com: no such host

I used Mac OS (Apple M1 Pro) and assume something is wrong with proxy settings.

Tried to login , was expecting login happen without an issue.

Answer (score 1):

If Docker isn't able to use the MacOS system proxy settings, you can set them manually. Go to `Docker > Preferences > Resources > Proxies` and adjust the settings as needed to match what your browser is using.